# How to get item list that will expire within 3 months from now in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have an inventory system, I need to get all items that will expire within 3 months. the column expire_date  is varchar with format like 01/2024 (m/Y). I have try this slution but not working. can you help in this matter please ?

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
        $threeMonthsLater = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 months', strtotime($currentDate)));
        $sql = "SELECT `medicine`.*,
        `supplier`.`s_id`,`s_name`
        FROM `medicine`
        LEFT JOIN `supplier` ON `medicine`.`supplier_id`=`supplier`.`s_id` 
        WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01/', expire_date), '%d%m/%Y') BETWEEN '$currentDate' AND '$threeMonthsLater'";
```

I implement this code but nothing fetching.

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
        $threeMonthsLater = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 months', strtotime($currentDate)));
        $sql = "SELECT `medicine`.*,
        `supplier`.`s_id`,`s_name`
        FROM `medicine`
        LEFT JOIN `supplier` ON `medicine`.`supplier_id`=`supplier`.`s_id` 
        WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01/', expire_date), '%d%m/%Y') BETWEEN '$currentDate' AND '$threeMonthsLater'";
```

Comment: _"the column expire_date is varchar"_ - okay, so go and **fix** that first of all. Use a proper DATE type. Trying to use `BETWEEN` with a `d/m/Y` format _can't_ work, this does string comparison (so f.e. `30/11/1990` would be considered _greater than_ `17/01/2024`)

Comment: Thank for your reply, I have to insert only like m/Y that why is on varchar. how to do so then ? any solution to append 1 at first ? like 01/m/Y.

Comment: What is stopping you from storing a _proper_ date, setting the day _always_ to the 1st, if it has no meaning anyway? _"any solution to append 1 at first ? like 01/m/Y"_ - you won't be able to do proper comparisons using this format. You will at least have to change this to a proper "order" of the date parts, make it Y/m/d or Y-m-d or something. String comparison works character-by-character, from left to right. You _could_ bring both into this format inside your query dynamically - but it would really be much, _much_ better to store a proper DATE to begin with.

Comment: i guess you missed a slash in your format string `'%d%m/%Y'` between %d and %m. otherwise your where condition is correct, but slow, since expire_date is not stored as date and as such cannot use index when comparing. you also don't need php to calculate periods, just use `BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 3 MONTH`

Comment: Try changing this: 
   STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01/', expire_date), '%d%m/%Y')
To this: 
   STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01/', expire_date), '%d/%m/%Y')

I think you were missing a '/' in the format string.

Comment: thanks you all  its working now  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01/', expire_date), '%d%m/%Y') To this: STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01/', expire_date), '%d/%m/%Y')

Comment: My second question, I need to get the already expired items but the current month should be excluded from that lists. try many thing but still not working.  like $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
        
        $sql = "SELECT `medicine`.*,
        `supplier`.`s_id`,`s_name`
        FROM `medicine`
        LEFT JOIN `supplier` ON `medicine`.`supplier_id`=`supplier`.`s_id` 
        WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(expire_date, '%m/%Y') < LAST_DAY('$currentDate')";

Comment: The issue of this solution its still included the current month $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
        $lastDayOfCurrentMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of this month'));
        
        $sql = "SELECT `medicine`.*,
        `supplier`.`s_id`,`s_name`
        FROM `medicine`
        LEFT JOIN `supplier` ON `medicine`.`supplier_id`=`supplier`.`s_id` 
        WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01/', expire_date), '%d/%m/%Y') < '$currentDate' AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01/', expire_date), '%d/%m/%Y') < '$lastDayOfCurrentMonth'";